# wxPython: centering an image in a panel

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a GridSizer with StaticBitmap images in it. I want to put each of the images in their own panels so I can change the background color to highlight an image if it has been selected. When I try to do this, however, the images are not centered in their panels and the highlighted background color is only present on two borders. How can I make the images in the center of their panels so there is an equivalent border around all sides of each?

```
sizer = wx.GridSizer(rows=row,cols=cols,vgap=5)
for fn in filenames:
    p = wx.Panel(self.panel)
    img = wx.Image(fn, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
    img2 = wx.StaticBitmap(p, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
    img2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnClick, img2)
    sizer.Add(p)
self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add your image to a `boxSizer` with a border.
You could write an `imagePanel` class to implement this.

You should then be able to call  `SetBackgroundColour` on your `ImgPanels` to change the borders (panels) colour when ever you need to.

Here's a **very** rough example for an `ImgPanel` class

```
class ImgPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, image):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        img = wx.Image(image, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.sBmp = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(img))

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(item=self.sBmp, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('green')
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
```